# What is the name of this site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Since this site now includes TV in its scope, should it really still be called "Movies"? That seems like a wildly inaccurate name for this site now.

Comment: As a rule of thumb *changing* urls on the internet is a bad idea. If you assimilate another one, and redirect them all to a single one, that's fine, but you lose a lot of SEO when you have advertising out there that was going to go to your site that now won't because you changed it.

Answer (score 9):

Tyler's Stack Overflow/Server Fault example does not hold because those are 'brand name' titles for those communities. Think about [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) - it's about both Unix systems and Linux systems, so they are both reflected in the title. [Science Fiction and Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) is another example. In both of these cases, the URL has just one of the title words in it - unix and scifi, respectively - but the title contains both elements.

Also: if Movies ever hopes to merge with TV, then TV would need to be in the title.

I keep hearing that this Movies site is not about TV, it's just a Movies site that allows questions about TV. To me this is like saying that we are a site about French language, but we are also going to allow the occasional question about Italian or Spanish. That makes no sense - just call the site Romance Languages, so everyone is immediately clear on what the site is about.

Comment: Hmm, good point >.>  Any word from the team then about merging this with TV?

Comment: @TylerShads since TV isn't a real site yet, all we would need to do is a) make TV on topic here (done), and b) tell people committed to TV that they can come over here, then c) shut down that proposal. No tech-stuff required - it's just up to the individual communities.

Answer (score 8):

I think this could be similar to [Sci-Fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), where the URL is scifi.stackexchange but the header of the site says Sci-Fi & Fantasy. I get that changing the URL is probably a big ask, but changing the banner up top to "Movies & TV" should probably only be a design ask.

Answer (score 6):

I personally would like the name Moving Pictures, but I don't think anyone else would.

I don't see an issue with changing the title to "Movies and TV", but changing the url would be a pain.